# How to connect to remote Redis server by to UserName and Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to connect to  Redis to cache sessions I used Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider
I can't access the Redis server Because I have username and password Not the accessKey

I used
this configuration

```
    <add name="RedisSessionStateStore"   applicationName="{App_}"  type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
            host="MyServerIp" port = "6379" accessKey="Password" ssl="false" />
```

here Exception is
Error: NOAUTH Authentication required. Verify if the Redis password provided is correct.

then I edit configuration to

```
<add name="RedisSessionStateStore" applicationName="{jam2_}" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
            connectionString="redis://username:'Password'@host" ssl="false" />
```

here Exception is
UnableToConnect on rediss://username:'password'@host:6379/Interactive

Comment: Why did you put single quotes around password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connectionString` expects a [StackExchange.Redis connection string](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html#configuration-options), so in your case that would be:

```
<add name="RedisSessionStateStore" applicationName="{jam2_}" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
            connectionString="host,password=Password,ssl=false" />
```